# Why is FM modulation not used in modern cellular communication?

Tags: bluetooth, modulation, cellular

Both bluetooth and celular links use GHz level carrier waves. Yet the modulation techniques are very different. I know why FM is more resilient to noise comparing to AM.

But why is FM preferred for bluetooth and PSK, FSK ect. is used for modern cellular communication even though both have similar carrier frequencies? It is a large topic but I was looking for some reasoning behind not using FM for cellular communication.

Comment: FM is primarily an analog modulation technique. Given a digital input it would translate to FSK but there are far more efficient options which make for a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

FSK is a digital adaptation of FM. PSK is a digital adaptation of AM. The same ideas apply just the implementation is different due to tighter control of channels and timing.

Bluetooth specifically uses GFSK, gaussian FSK. It does not use FM as an analog radio station would.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109191/discussion-on-answer-by-passerby-why-is-fm-modulation-not-used-in-modern-cellula).

Answer (score 1):

The original cell phones did use FM to/from the handsets, because Motorola had vast experience with FM during WW2 and perhaps before in business radios.

The original cell frequency allocations were on 30,000 Hz channel spacings, suitable for narrow-band modulation, which produces sidebands similar to AM sidebands.

For quality conversation, the RF links required about +20dB signal_noise ratio.

Switching to digital designs allows this SNR to be reduced by 15 or 18dB, and the system designs greatly alter.